# Ords auto REST - setting default number of rows returned by auto rest query

Tags: oracle, autorest, oracle-ords

We're using ORDS for internal applications and find auto REST to be very handy for quick, simple applications. When we enable rest services on a table or view we only get 25 rows by default. Trying to set "misc.pagination.maxRows" in defaults.xml such as 1500  does not affect the rest enabled schema objects however.

Is there a way to reset the pagination limit for auto-REST? currently we're having to force it with the limit parameter such as: ?limit=5000

currently using version: 18.2.0.r1831332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, the AUTO feature isn't really configurable - so if you want a higher pagination size, you can force it, or you can build your own GET handler for your SELECT * FROM service.

The maxRows parameter sets the high water mark for the size of a page tied to a query, not the default or low side.

Comment: thanks Jeff. We can continue to force it using the limit parameter, good point about the maxrows entry - clearly its in the name I was just hoping for a quick fix :)

Comment: auto is a great feature until you start needing to deviate from the base features delivered...then you're ready to build your own services